# backbone router globbing non backbone routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm using devise, rails with backbone. All my backbone routes are working just fine. But non-backbone routes like /accounts/login that are supposed to rendered by rails are being globbed with backbone router.

```
SS.Routers.ApplicationRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.el = $("#content");
  },

  routes: {
    "": "home"
  },

  "home": function () {
    console.debug("Got home request");
    var view = new SS.Views.Home();
    this.el.empty().append(view.render());
  }
});
```

The actual request/response to the /accounts/login is happening from rails logs. But Backbone home root gets triggered afterwards and my home page is rendered.

My layout has

```
  $(function () {
    SS.init();
  });
```

from

```
window.SS = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {Providers: {}},
  Routers: {},
  init: function (data) {
    console.debug("Initializing Backbone Components");
    new SS.Routers.ApplicationRouter();
    new SS.Routers.ProvidersRouter();
    if (!Backbone.history.started) {
      Backbone.history.start();
      Backbone.history.started = true;
    };
  }
};
```

Which is triggering my home route again.

"" route in backbone is not supposed to be globbing /accounts/login but it is.

A little bit of debugging is showing me that /accounts/login is being gobbled by "" since the fragment is an empty string.

And the fragment is an empty string in the all the cases where there is no match for backbone routes.

Code from backbone 0.9.2

```
loadUrl: function(fragmentOverride) {
      var fragment = this.fragment = this.getFragment(fragmentOverride);
      var matched = _.any(this.handlers, function(handler) {
        if (handler.route.test(fragment)) {
          console.debug(handler);
          console.debug(fragment);
          handler.callback(fragment);
          return true;
        }
      });
      return matched;
    },
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `/accounts/login` a normal link or AJAX? How does it get accessed?

Comment: Yes. Its a traditional link, no ajax.

Comment: And what page does it return with? Is it there that the Backbone route is getting triggered?

Comment: Home page is rendered. For some reason /account/login gets matched with backbone "" route.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you navigate to `/accounts/login`?

Comment: /accounts/login is a direct link in html. Something like <a href='/accounts/login'> Login </a>

Comment: I'm dealing with this problem right now. Did you find a solution? Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: and what contains ProvidersRouter?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class ('passThrough') or 'data-passThrough=true' attribute to the link.  Catch this class/attribute in your router and return true so Backbone stops handling it and the browser treats it as a regular link.